# Let $x=\begin{bmatrix}3\cr4\end{bmatrix}$ and $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&x^T\cr x&0\end{bmatrix}$ is A diagonizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, problem-solving

I had a problem: **let $x=\begin{bmatrix}3\cr4\end{bmatrix}$ and $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&x^T\cr x&0\end{bmatrix}$ is A diagonizable?**

But when I plug in the matrix x and its transpose into A the dimensions don't work out and we have empty slots where there should be elements and I was wondering if I'm just tripping or if this problem is unsolvable?

Comment: You should have a symmetric $3\times 3$ matrix. The lower right $0$ is representing a $2\times 2$ block $0$-matrix.

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=JordanDecomposition%5B%7B%7B0%2C+3%2C+4%7D%2C+%7B3%2C+0%2C+0%7D%2C+%7B4%2C+0%2C+0%7D%7D%5D) says diagonalizable with characteristic polynomial $25 \lambda - \lambda^3$.

Comment: In fact, without too much effort we can show that the eigenvalues of this matrix will be $0, \pm \|x\|$. For instance, we could note that $A = BC$, with 
$$
B = \pmatrix{x & 0\\0 & 1}, \quad C = \pmatrix{0&1\\x^T & 0},
$$
and $BC$ has the same non-zero eigenvalues as $CB$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably the bottom right $0$ is actually a $2 \times 2$ matrix of $0$, i.e.
$$A = \left[\matrix{0 & 3 & 4\cr 3 & 0 & 0\cr 4 & 0 & 0\cr} \right]$$

Comment: And the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $ch_A(x)=x(x-5)(x+5)$ and therefore $A$ is diagonizable.